# form's submit button not working. Can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

```
<form id="contactForm" name="enquiryform" method="POST" action="enquirymail.php" class="contact-form">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required data-error="Please enter your name">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input type="email" class="email form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required data-error="Please enter your email">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="msg_subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required data-error="Please enter your message subject">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <textarea id="message" rows="7" placeholder="Massage" class="form-control" required data-error="Write your message"></textarea>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="contact-btn">Submit</button>
        <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this is my script : - -----------------------------------------

```
< script >
    $(function() {

        $('#contactForm').on('#submit', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://companyname.in/enquirymail.php',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    alert('form was submitted');
                }
            });

        });

    }); < /script>
```

Comment: `.on('#submit'` There is no such event as `#submit`

Answer (score 3):

As the .`submit()` method is just a shorthand for `.on( "submit", handler )`, detaching is possible using `.off( "submit" )`

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://companyname.in/enquirymail.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function() {
            alert('form was submitted');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `#submit` in your code which is not allowed for `submit` method. `#` is used to access `id` attribute of the element and perform an event like `click` `change` or other event to perform an operation.

You have to use `submit` directly to submit your form. Hope this will help you to understand what actually `submit` and '#submit` do.

```
< script > $(function() {

    $('#contactForm').on('submit', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://companyname.in/enquirymail.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert('form was submitted');
            }
        });

    });

}); < /script>
```

try this ..

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this would solve OP's problem.

Comment: you have to target the event 'submit' what he has done was targeting the even like '#submit' which the compiler won't recognize

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the `.on()` line:

```
$("#contactForm").on("#submit", function(e) {...}
```

You have `#submit` as an event, which is invalid - it doesn't exist. You want to use `submit` instead:

```
$("#contactForm").on("submit", function(e) {...}
```

Full working JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#contactForm').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://companyname.in/enquirymail.php',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    alert('form was submitted');
                }
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answer will help you.

**When listening to an event,we just need to pass and event name instead of passing of #submit as an ID. You just remove # from line 3.**

You did,

```
$("#contactForm").on("#submit", function(e) {/* do here*/}
```

But it should be :

```
$("#contactForm").on("submit", function(e) {/*Write your own logic here*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<script>$("#contactForm").on("submit", function(e) {...}
```